# How do I specify a whitelisted domain when using SignalR and CORS

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a website http://beta.foo.com that needs to talk to http://socket.foo.com.  I've configured CORS on http://socket.foo.com as specified in this example:  http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain

The socket connects properly.  I'd like to restrict the list of permitted domains to *.foo.com.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the overloads of `UseCors` to find out which other options you have. For example, code like this:

```
var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicy
{
    AllowAnyHeader = true,
    AllowAnyMethod = true
};
corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://*.foo.com");

map.UseCors(
    new CorsOptions
    {
        PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
        {
            PolicyResolver = r => Task.FromResult(corsPolicy)
        }
    });
```

should put you in the right direction.